# Find the shortest path of two points P and Q on a cone

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, recreational-mathematics, surfaces

The solution is like this:
Open the cone and make it flat, and connect two points P and Q with a straight line.

But I cannot understand why it is possible to cut a cone and make it flat.

Is it obvious or not?

By the way, it is possible to cut a cylinder and make it flat and it is impossible to cut a sphere and make it flat.

Comment: Yes, this is completely obvious. https://frogprincepaperie.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/christmas-paper-cone-tree-5.jpg

Comment: But I do not think it is obvious. What should I do? What is mathematical formulation and proof?

Comment: You should get a piece of paper, make it into a cone as shown on that picture, tape it togehter, then cut it open and lay it flat to see that it can be done. Alternatively, cut out a circle of paper, remove a wedge from that circle (make a "pac-man"), join the two edges of the cut and see that you get a cone from a perfectly flat piece of paper.

Comment: You were asking "why it is possible".

Comment: A link for the question in title https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140636/what-is-the-shortest-path-equation-between-2-points-on-a-cone/140886#140886

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) of the surface in question. A surface can be cut and made flat if and only if its Gaussian curvature is equal to that of the plane, i.e. zero.

The cone and cylinder have zero Gaussian curvature, so can be flattened *while preserving distances*, which explains the validity of the solution to the shortest-path-on-a-cone problem. The sphere has positive Gaussian curvature and cannot be flattened in a similar manner, which has long been a source of frustration among cartographers.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Parcly Taxel. Your answer is what I wanted to know.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Er, sorry, the hyperboloid of one sheet has negative Gaussian curvature.

Comment: Yep, you are right, sorry. Now I can just go hang myself. (And I can't undownvote :-( )

Comment: Only "flattened while preserving distances" *locally*!!

Comment: Oh Prof. Theodore Shifrin. I bought your book "Multivariable Mathematics" in April because your book is recommended in Michael Spivak's "Calculus 4th Edition". Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Surfaces that can be made flat are called developable. They need to be ruled, i.e. made of straight lines, like cylindres and cones, but this is not enough.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, Mr Yves Daoust.